# How to store user uploaded files after app deployment?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file-upload, upload, multer

I know this question had been asked before, but I'm looking for a cleaner answer.

I am deploying an app where users can upload images.

So far I made it so that the files get stored locally on my machine, but I have no clue if the files will still be uploaded to that directory, once the app is deployed.

Do I have to make that folder public somehow or is it best practice to use and online cloud storage of some sort and if yes, please give recommendations.

Also is there a way to protect that folder from say malicious files?

Comment: Hi. You can store the files in your local folder even after deploying the project. But this is applicable if you will get less number of files gets uploaded to your project.

Comment: To achieve this only thing you need to do is, providing your folder path in the place of file upload functionality exactly where you have given the path of your local folder to store the images. Folder path must be in this format. ```http://sitename:port/folder/``` It depends upon your folder structure.